Undetected ChromeDriver still activates captcha when used in Selenium
Basically, I am trying to login to Snapchat but it triggers the captcha every time, so to try to avoid this I read about undetected chrome driver here: https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/blob/master/undetected_chromedriver/devtool.py
I decided to give it a try but the captcha still gets activated..here is my code below:
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
self.driver = uc.Chrome()

def login(self):
        print('GET LOGIN')
        self.driver.get("https://accounts.snapchat.com/accounts/v2/login")

        print(self.user_creds['username'])
        try:
            accept_all_button = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[span[contains(text(), 'Accept All')]]")
            accept_all_button.click()
            print("Clicked 'Accept All' button to remove overlapping elements.")
            time.sleep(5)  # Wait for the page to update
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"'Accept All' button not found, proceeding to click 'Accept' button.{e}")

        # Wait for the username input to be present
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "accountIdentifier"))
        )
        print('found 1')
        username_input = self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, "accountIdentifier")
        
        username_input.send_keys(self.user_creds['username'])
        print('found 2',username_input)
        time.sleep(3)
        next_button =WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Next')]"))
        )
        #next_button = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "btn.btn-lg.btn-default")
        print("next",next_button)
        
        time.sleep(2)  # Give some time for the scrolling to complete
        next_button.click()

        print('found 3')
       
        time.sleep(10)
        
        try:
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h1[@class='login-challenge-title' and contains(text(), 'Log in to Snapchat')]"))
            )
            print("Element found: Log in to Snapchat")
        except Exception as e:
            print("Element not found: Log in to Snapchat")

        password_input = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password"))
        )
        password_input.send_keys(self.user_creds['password'])
        password_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        print('found 4')
        # Wait for some time to ensure login is processed
        time.sleep(10)
        
        print("Logged in successfully!")


Does anyone have experience in using this package and getting bypass captcha?

This question is similar to: How can I bypass the Google CAPTCHA with Selenium and Python?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hey @Anerdw thank you for responding. I read that already and it doesn't rly solve my case. The capthca am getting is way more advanced plus this doesn't really mention the undetected chromedriver. So I would like to see if anyone else had similar issues with these things. What happens is when I run the chromedriver with undetected, after I enter username the capthca still appears before I can proceed to login.

Just to check - the answers below the top one as well? (That might sound silly but I have to ask since not everybody reads all the answers.)

Yes, you mean comments on the top answer right?

No, answers besides the top one.

it's a moving target... might check their forum: https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/discussions
